# Ng bootstrap radio buttons

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am using NG-Bootstrap radio buttons like this

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="model">
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="2"> Middle
  </label>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="3"> Right
  </label>
</div>
```

And in compoment

```js
this.radioGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'model': 1,
});
```

It is working OK, because all button are in one line, but what if I need different html that third
button will be on another place in html, i have tried something like this

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="model">
   <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
   </label>
   <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
      <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="2"> Middle
   </label>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="model">
      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="3"> Right
      </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

But it does not work, does it need to be wrapped in a group??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [the source code of the ngbRadioGroup](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/radio.ts#L14), I believe you guess is right - we need to wrap a group. I would expect we can use `ng-container` to avoid addition HTML:

```html
<ng-container ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" formControlName="model">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" >
       <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
       </label>
       <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
          <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="2"> Middle
       </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
          <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn-primary">
            <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="3"> Right
          </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```